# Como agrupar o ng-repeat em AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, laravel, ng-repeat

Preciso Agrupar o campo Aula e listar as tarefas que existem, mas não consigo fazer isso com o AngularJS.

Aqui está minha view:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div ng-controller="atividadesDisciplinaController">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Recurso</th>
                    <th>Visualizações</th>
                    <th>Interações</th>
                    <th>Último Acesso</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="x in disciplinas">
                    <td>@{{ x.recurso }}</td>
                    <td>@{{ x.visualizacao }}</td>
                    <td>@{{ x.interacao }}</td>
                    <td>@{{ x.ultimo_acesso }}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Aqui listo a Controller que recebe um JSON:

```
<script>
    app.controller('atividadesDisciplinaController', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.post("/disciplina/{{ $slug }}/relatorios/{{$relatorio}}")
            .then(function (response) {$scope.disciplinas = response.data;});
    });
</script>
```

Hoje está listando assim.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E eu preciso que fique mais ou menos assim
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Testei usando a documentação do AngularJS:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in disciplinas | groupBy: 'aula'">
    <td>@{{ x.recurso }}</td>
    <td>@{{ x.visualizacao }}</td>
    <td>@{{ x.interacao }}</td>
    <td>@{{ x.ultimo_acesso }}</td>
</tr>
```

E me retorna um erro:

> ```
> Unknown provider: groupByFilterProvider <- groupByFilter
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o [`Angular-filter`](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) como complemento do seu projeto e realizar o que deseja com dois `ng-repeat`:

```js
angular
  .module('ModuloTabelas', ['angular.filter'])
  .controller('ControllerTabelas', ControllerTabelas);

ControllerTabelas.$inject = [];

function ControllerTabelas() {
  var tabelas = this;
  tabelas.disciplinas = [];

  iniciar();

  function iniciar() {
    tabelas.disciplinas.push({
      aula: 'Aula 1',
      recurso: 'Primeiro',
      visualizacao: 2,
      interacao: 1,
      ultimo_acesso: 'xxxx'
    });
    
    tabelas.disciplinas.push({
      aula: 'Aula 1',
      recurso: 'Segundo',
      visualizacao: 0,
      interacao: 1,
      ultimo_acesso: 'xxxx'
    });
    
    tabelas.disciplinas.push({
      aula: 'Aula 2',
      recurso: 'Terceiro',
      visualizacao: 2,
      interacao: 1,
      ultimo_acesso: 'xxxx'
    });
    
    tabelas.disciplinas.push({
      aula: 'Aula 2',
      recurso: 'Quarto',
      visualizacao: 2,
      interacao: 1,
      ultimo_acesso: 'xxxx'
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.17/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div ng-app="ModuloTabelas">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div ng-controller="ControllerTabelas as tabelas">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Recurso</th>
              <th>Visualizações</th>
              <th>Interações</th>
              <th>Último Acesso</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody ng-repeat="(key, value) in tabelas.disciplinas | groupBy: 'aula'">
            <tr><td colspan="4">{{ key }}</td></tr>
            <li ng-repeat="player in value">
              player: {{ player.name }} 
            </li>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in value">
              <td>{{ x.recurso }}</td>
              <td>{{ x.visualizacao }}</td>
              <td>{{ x.interacao }}</td>
              <td>{{ x.ultimo_acesso }}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas testei com o grouBy e me retorna um erro.
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: groupByFilterProvider <- groupByFilter

Comment: @JonathanAugustoHalberstadt você adicionou a importação do script e no módulo?

Comment: refiz como você disse e agora está retornando outro erro.
Não entendo muito disso, pode me explicar como trago as disciplinas ao invés de usar aquele push que você fez?

angular.js:12221 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ControllerTabelas' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: Não entendi. Foi marcado como resposta aceita mais você conseguiu resolver o problema?